# opamp comparator circuit question battery discharger tester arduino

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, circuit-design

[image]
http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=8377.0

I have wanting to build a battery discharger/tester for age. I saw this circuit years ago, and thought it's great, but was too complicated to me to build back then. now I come back to this, and I have few questions for this circuit design.

1. why there isn't a current limiting resistor between the output of the op-amp and the base of the NPN? and won't this current from the op-amp added to the total capacity of the battery?
2. D2 is the voltage reading point. It uses a 0.5 ohm resistor as current sensor. if the discharging current is 500ma, then the voltage is v=IR= 0.5A * 0.5 ohm = 0.25v; 1A>0.5V; 100ma>0.05V; For an arduino analog pin with limited resolution.(5-0v 1024; 5/1024=0.0048v) How accurate will it be?
3. A relay is used to end the discharging process. Will it be more simple by using a LOW digital output on the base of the NPN instead? Or maybe it's also okay to use a LOW digital output on the Vref of the op-amp?

Answer (score 2):

> why there isn't a current limiting resistor between the output of the
>   op-amp and the base of the NPN? and won't this current from the op-amp
>   added to the total capacity of the battery?

The emitter is forced to be at Vref (due to feedback) so, in effect the circuit can be regarded as an emitter follower and, as such a base resistor is not needed. However, given that a relay can disconnect the main power source to the TIP41C, I would think it's a good idea to use one.

> For an arduino analog pin with limited resolution.(5-0v 1024;
>   5/1024=0.0048v) How accurate will it be?

You are confusing resolution with accuracy. If you want to understand the accuracy take into account INL, DNL, zero offset and gain slope errors stated inside the data sheet for the Arduino.

> A relay is used to end the discharging process. Will it be more simple
>   by using a LOW digital output on the base of the NPN instead? Or maybe
>   it's also okay to use a LOW digital output on the Vref of the op-amp?

I would go for clamping Vref to 0V to limit the current but bear in mind the input offset voltage of the LM324 can add a small error and cause several tens of microamps still to flow. Maybe choose a much better op-amp. I would use a MOSFET to clamp Vref or maybe an analogue switch.

Answer (score 0):

To your first question. Putting a resistor in series with the op amp would require more voltage from the op amp, and for an LM324 powered by 5 volts, there isn't a lot of voltage swing to spare. Also, an op amp is typically protected against output short circuits.

As for the op amp current, that actually decreases the battery current, rather than increasing it. The sense resistor sets the current in the resistor at some level, but that current is equal to the sum of the base and collector currents. This is not a problem in your case, since the transistor will [typically have a gain of 20 to 40](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/TI/TIP41C.pdf), which means that the error produced by the base current will be in the range of 2 1/2 to 5 per cent. If you need more accuracy, either use a transistor with higher gain, or use a MOSFET, which draws no current through the gate (for low frequencies).

Responding to your second question. If you want to drive this circuit from an Arduino analog output, you should not use the circuit as shown.

Start by determining what your maximum current should be. Let's say 1 amp. As you have realized, this means 0.5 volts across the sense resistor, and about 0.5 volts at the op amp. Instead of your circuit as shown, try

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT62ZA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R1 and R2 form a 10 to 1 voltage divider, and 0 to 5 volts in will produce 0 to 0.5 volts at the op amp. Since the input voltage scales exactly to the load current, the tester's resolution will be $$ \Delta i = \frac{1 \text{ amp}}{1023} = .977\text{ mA}$$